# Check if a PySpark column matches regex and create new column based on results

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe which looks like this:

```
df:
+----+--------------------+
|  ID|               Email|
+----+--------------------+
|2345|  sample@example.org|
|2398| sample2@example.org|
|2328|   sampleexample.org|
|3983|   sample@exampleorg|
+----+--------------------+
```

I want to apply regex to the above dataframe (email column) and add a new column based on the results of the match (True or False). My regex:

```
regex = '^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$'
```

Basically checking whether it is a valid email or not. And the desired output is:

```
df2:
+----+--------------------+--------+
|  ID|               Email| Matched|
+----+--------------------+--------+
|2345|  sample@example.org|    True|
|2398| sample2@example.org|    True|
|2328|   sampleexample.org|   False|
|3983|   sample@exampleorg|   False|
+----+--------------------+--------+
```

I am only aware of the dataframe `filter` which would remove those that do not match the pattern and that is not the desired outcome. I also thought about using that regex as a function and apply it to the email column, and do something like the following:

```
def check(email):  
    if(re.search(regex, email)):  
        return True
    else:  
        return False
udf_check_email = udf(check, BooleanType())
df.withColumn('matched', udf_check_email(df.email)).show()
```

But I am not sure whether this is the most efficient way of doing it.

Answer (score 8):

we can use `SQL rlike` function as,

```
df = df.withColumn('matched',F.when(df.email.rlike('^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$'),True).otherwise(False))
```